# Wondering if its possible to send audio output of VLC/Viber to headphones and output of Clementine/Amarok to laptop speakers

Tags: 16.04, sound, kubuntu, multimedia

I am using Kubuntu 16.04 on a HP Envy 15 with the following specs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)

00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)

00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev ff)

07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)

09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)

0f:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

The laptop came with Windows 8.1 preinstalled (obviously, can't have people buying computers without paying the MS tax now, can we?) and before I wiped it and installed Kubuntu 14.04 on it, I noticed that I could direct the output of individual application groups (Video, Music, Communications) to the laptop's speakers or to the headphones. I thought that was a pretty nifty trick.

In Kubuntu 16.04, from the Multimedia module of KDE Plasma 5 desktop's System Settings, I can do something similar with one caveat, while it lets me choose between HDMI output, built in output and bluetooth devices, it bundles the headphones and internal laptop speakers together in a single entry so I can, for instance, send the output of Viber to built in output, audio out of VLC to HDMI and audio out of Amarok to a Bluetooth speaker but if the heaphones are connected, I can't send any output to the laptop's internal speakers. Is there any possible work around?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

--
Regards
iKazmi